# How to get row number in custom Prototype Cell file

Tags: swift2, ios9, viewcontroller, uitableview

I have created a custom prototype cell and "peopleTableViewCell.swift" file for that cell.
The cell has a button delete and after clicking on delete, I want that row to get deleted.

The IBAction for the button is in the "peopleTableViewCell.swift" file.

How to pass the row number from "viewController.swift" file to "peopleTableViewCell.swift"

Please Help......

Comment: is the `indexPath` not accurate enough for you? on the other hand I have no idea what you want to achieve, and why you'd even want to pass the _"row-number"_ from a view-contoller to a view. makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can get IndexPath in UITableViewCell subclass using this code.

### Objective C

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [(UITableView *)self.superview.superview indexPathForCell: self];
      NSLog(@"Row : %d", indexPath.row);
}
```

### Swift

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    if let tableView : UITableView = self.superview.superview as! UITableView?{

        let indexForCell : NSIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(self)!
        let row = indexForCell.row
        print("Row : \(row)")
    }


}
```

Comment: can you please answer my previous question

Comment: no i mean i have posted one more question with auto Layout problem..... so all am asking you to please have look at it.... thanks you so much....

Comment: Ok, i will look at that, but you can accept my answer if your issue fixed.

Comment: Also post answer for your AutoLayout Issue. Thanks

Comment: here it alwaz goes in else part

Comment: Edit answer, try now.